# Does anyone know of a tool that links to my regional Amazon Review Page?

Tags: linker, review

I'm not a programmer. The closest I've come to understanding code was writing in Basic on my Commodore many years ago. I'm an author.
What I'd like to find is a tool that will create a link whereby my reader can click and be directed to the review page for a specific book on their regional Amazon site.
I had such a tool but it has stopped working and the developer says he isn't interested in maintaining it.
Any suggestions?

There are tools that will redirect to the Amazon sales page but, in reality, most people can't be bothered searching for the exact correct spot to leave their review. I want to make it as easy for them as possible.